# How to find index creation date in MarkLogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

Is there an XQuery to identify when an index would have been added ? One way is to check all historical changes in databases.xml but what if that has been rolled over  many times?

Comment: What do you mean by "Index have been added"? Do you want to figure our when someone has created new index on the database or you want to identify when something has been added into the index? Please clarify

Comment: I want to know the index creation date.

Comment: I want to know when someone has created new index on the database

Comment: You can get this by MarkLogic generated log files but MarkLogic does not preserve all the log file by default.